# Play Framework run in production: Bad root server path /var/project/play.crypto.secret

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I successfully deployed Play Framework application on two servers but on two others I've got strange error when try to start it: Bad root server path /var/project/play.crypto.secret
I've got this error when I try to run it like this ./project -Dconfig.file=/opt/production.conf and when I try to run it just ./project
I have play.crypto.secret in my production.conf
What should I look at to find the cause of the problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The cause of the problem was application.ini file with secret in it

Comment: so what should the application.ini look like?

Comment: Well, I just deleted it

Comment: application.ini in conf, delete it, then i can work. +1